# gem: mail: how to read email from all folders including inbox

Tags: ruby, email

```
 * mail (2.7.1)
        Summary: Mail provides a nice Ruby DSL for making, sending and reading emails.
        Homepage: https://github.com/mikel/mail
        Path: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.6.6/gems/mail-2.7.1
```

The mail client in use, Thunderbird, has rules on some clients which move mail from the `inbox` to other specified `folders`.

Need help to read emails held in `folders` OTHER THAN `inbox`, for example, `sent`, `cC` etc.

The documentation seems to be silent on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in mail/network/retriever_methods/imap.rb where the mailbox to search is set as an option as follows:
`options[:mailbox]=` where `options` is passed as the only parameter of `Mail.find`.

By default, it is set to `INBOX`.

To search the mailbox `Sent` folder use: `options[:mailbox] = 'INBOX.Sent'`.

Also, when constructing the search key, use the verb conjunction `to` as opposed to `from` in the case of the `Sent` folder.